# How can I handle abnormal exit error, for example, performing a function before it exit abnormally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit

During a long repeated Monte Carlo runs, for example, I want to terminate my program before it exits normally (Like for 10000MC runs, I want to terminate when 5000 runs have been finished. But I still want to get the results of the previous 5000 runs.), or it ran into some unexpected error, it exits abruptly with losing previous results.  Is it possible to perform a function (like saving some results/variables I want) before it exits abnormally in PYTHON so that I can keep already obtained results?

Comment: When you say exits abnormally, does that mean it raises an exception? Do you get some kind of stack trace that indicates a failure? Could you please try to craft a practical [MCVE] of this problem to help illustrate this better?

Comment: Do you mean something like a `try`/`except` construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your code in `try/finally`, and save the obtained results to a file in the `finally` statement. This will execute the code in `finally` whether or not your code exited abnormally. An abnormal exit includes the case when you intentionally interrupt the script midway execution by pressing `CTRL+C` (which raises KeyboardInterrupt exception).

```python
import pickle

def MC_SIMULATION():
    # your code
    return something

results = []
i = 0
try:
    for _ in range(10000):
        results.append(MC_SIMULATION())
        i += 1
finally: #runs whether or not an exception was raised in the try statement
    with open("MC_"+str(i)+".pickle",'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(results, f)
```

Now you can either wait for the script to finish and save results, or interrupt it in the middle with `CTRL+C` and the results obtained so far will still be saved.

Comment: Thank you so much! I try it. It works no matter whether there is an error or I deliberately terminate the program during the running in the terminal. I currently do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer though!

Comment: you can accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers